# method must be compatible with interface method

Tags: php

I have an interface that defines a method `charge()`, the first parameter is required and the second one is optional, and my layout looks something like this:

```
interface Process{

    public function charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId = null);

    // Other items

}

abstract class CardProcessor implements Process{

    // Some methods & properties are here

}

class Authorize extends CardProcessor{

    public function charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId){
        // Process the card on profile
    }

}
```

When I load the file (even when I am not executing `charge()`) I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of src\processors\CardProcessors\Authorize::charge() must be compatible with src\interfaces\Process::charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId = NULL) in /home/processor/src/processors/CardProcessors/Authorize.php on line 19"

What is the reason for this? It looks right to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Process
{    
    public function charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId);   
    // Other items
}

abstract class CardProcessor implements Process 
{   
    // Some methods & properties are here
    public abstract function charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId);
}

class Authorize extends CardProcessor 
{    
    public function charge($customerProfileId, $paymentProfileId = null)
    {
        // Process the card on profile
    }    
}
```

- Added method signature to abstract class CardProcessor as suggested by @Dev Mode
- Took implementation
  out of interface ( var = null ) and put it in the concrete class.

Answer (score 2):

The signature for the charge method in your child class still has to match based on the original signature in the interface. It looks to me like your hierarchy still requires the matching signature.

From: [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

> Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. For example, if the child class defines an optional argument, where the abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the signature.

In addition, from [PHP Object Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

Comment: Are you saying I need to define it in the abstract class as well?

Comment: The implementing class has to match the interface's method signature, even if that class is abstract. Since in this case the child class would define that optional parameter, you'd want to define the last parameter there, along the lines of what Adam's answer below demonstrates.